# Does the final answer depend on the original expression or its simplified form?

Tags: probability

I came across this simple probability problem.

> From first $50$ natural numbers, a number is selected at random. Find the probability that selected number satisfies $$\left|\frac{3}{x-4}\right|>1$$

I solved it in this way:

Sample space is $^{50}C_1$

Case $1$: $\left(\frac{3}{x-4}\right)<-1$

$$\begin{array}{l|l}
\mathrm {When} \;x-4>0 &\mathrm{When}\;x-4<0\\
\implies x>4 & \implies x<4\\
\therefore 3<4-x & \therefore 3>4-x\\
\therefore x<1 & \therefore x>1\\
\mathrm {This \;is\;absurd} & \therefore x=2,3
\end{array}$$

Case  $2$: $\left(\frac{3}{x-4}\right)>1$
$$\begin{array}{l|l}
\mathrm {When} \;x-4>0 &\mathrm{When}\;x-4<0\\
\implies x>4 & \implies x<4\\
\therefore 3>x-4 & \therefore 3<x-4\\
\therefore x<7 & \therefore x>7\\
\therefore x=5,6 & \mathrm {This \;is\;absurd}
\end{array}$$

Thus, I got four values of $x$, namely, $2,3,5,6$ and hence, the probability is $4 \over 50$

Now, the book solved it in this way:

$$\left|\frac{3}{x-4}\right|>1 \implies |x-4|<3 \implies -3<x-4<3 \implies 1<x<7$$
$$\therefore x=2,3,4,5,6$$
Thus, probability is $5 \over 50$

What I wanna ask is, shouldn't $4$ be excluded? If we consider the original inequality, then putting $x=4$ doesn't satisfy it. However, it does satisfy when we put it in the simplified form, that is, $|x-4|<3$.

Often, in limit problems, we simplify the original expression to get a well-defined answer. Otherwise, just substituting the limit in the original expression gives us an indeterminate form. Does the same apply here?

Comment: I would not have included $4$.

Comment: This is a thoughtful question.  In response to your last paragraph, limits are explicitly concerned only with the values around a point but not exactly at the point itself; this justifies most of the algebraic simplification which tends to be valid away from the singularity of interest.  This context has no such justification.

Comment: But then, after simplification, don't we finally put that point in the place of the variable, and hence get the value of the limit?

Comment: The question is nonsense, since it requires determining whether the meaningless statement $|\frac{3}{0}| > 1$ is true. Write to the author, contact the professor, etc. But the fault is not yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Community wiki answer so the question can be marked as answered:

As has been stated in various comments, you're right and the book is wrong. Substituting $4$ into the inequality results in an undefined expression that cannot be said to be satisfied or not satisfied.